# Who was this pun intended on?

Tags: word-usage

Is the use "intended on" natural in this  context?

Someone says something that was satirical.  So the listener got it and jokingly asked:

> Who was this pun intended on?

Is the use of "intended on" natural or should it be "for"?

Comment: *Intended **to be used** on* would work. It's not clear if the omission of those words would have been part of the joke or not . . .

Comment: I would probably use "Who was this pun **directed at**?"

Comment: BTW, a pun is a play on words, and rarely satirical, a different form of humor (though it is possible to make a pun satirical). E.G. `The king would not eat a popover, because the bun is the lowest form of wheat.`

Comment: What about "intended for" @JasonBassford?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish In regular usage, *intended for* is fine. But, as I said, *intended on* might have been used deliberately in this case as part of the joke. The unusual use of language might have been what makes it funny. (It would depend on what the satirical comment was, as well as the rest of the dialogue in context.)